# How to connect two Dell storage arrays to a to a Dell Poweredge server (daisy chain vs direct)?

Tags: storage-area-network, dell, dell-poweredge, iscsi, sas

I purchased two Dell MD1000 storage arrays together with a Dell Poweredge 1950 server and need help setting them up (I am a complete novice to SAN/iSCSI).

The Poweredge server has two SAS SFF-8470 connectors. Should the two storage arrays (which have a one *EMM each) be connected via a daisy chain or directly into the Poweredge server?

Also, how does one access Dell OpenManage software? Is it a webgui and can it be accessed remotely or does it need to be accessed from the server itself? I have not turned them on as I am still waiting for delivery.

*EMM: Enclosure Management Module

Comment: FYI, this is not "SAN" nor *iSCSI. It is actually DAS (Direct Attached Storage) and SAS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stack the MD unit that way; (In the image its 3 MD, but you can see how)

[image]

For your openmanage question, yes, it can be used remotly, but be sure to set the routing correctly in the management card. (as some prefer to isolate the management network)